# 2-Way Handshaking (mutual authentication ) in Java Webservice for SOAP Request raising handshake_failure

Tags: java, web-services, soap, https, mutual-authentication

I need to implement the 2-Way Handshaking(mutual authentication) for SOAP request

2 - Way Handshaking is (mutual authentication),

In the request we need to send the SSL certificate to authenticate by server.
(Server will authenticate with pre-shared SSL certificate).

A-party - Server
B-party - Client (Me)

We have generated SSL certificate using,
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout B-party.key  -x509 -days 1000 -out B-party.cer

To import into trustStore
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file  B-party.cer -alias server -keystore B-partyr.jks

To import into trustStore
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file  A-party.cer  -alias server -keystore A-party.jks

1) A-party shared my Selfsigned SSL certificate(.cer) with B-party.
2) B-party shared their SSL certificate with A-party.
3) B-party imported the client Shared SSL certificate in their truststore successfully using keytool
4) A-party also Added the the certificate at their END.

Now B party generated JKS from B-party SSL certificate(.cer) using keytool.

(JKS contains Certificate and Key)

Before calling the stub(WSDL shared by A-party) we need set the System property to send the SSL cert in request,

As i know this is to send ssl cert in request (if not, correct me).

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "B-party.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "A-party.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");

System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
```

Now we called the Stub Method to perform the operation but we are receiving "handshake_failure".

Why Handshake exception raised as we know the same ssl certificate was sent in  the request.

Exception

> HTTPSender - Unable to sendViaPost to url[]
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Now we are sending the ssl certificate in JKS format will it acceptable by all servers , is server is cable of reading certificate from request.

**Is self signed certificate is send TLS Certificate Request ?**

If TLS Certificate Request is send by server, how to check whether that list has my self-signed certificate.

Comment: Hi have you found the solution, i am also facing the same issue

Comment: I have solved this by changing the keystore to pfx format(PKCS12). PFX file contains private-key and certificate.